# My function does not seem to be getting the value I need it to, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

Sorry for the vague and possibly dumb question, I am new to this stuff and don't have the vocabulary to know exactly what to ask. I am trying to create a guessing game with html and javascript in which a flag pops up and you guess what it is. However, my function seems to have issues I cannot find a solution for.

When I submit the form, nothing happens. I don't exactly know what the issue would be, possibly to do with trying to get link[random_num].value.toLowerCase() in my javascript code.

HTML:

````
`<div class="content">
        <div class="contentContainer">
            <div class="imageContainer">

                <script>
                    document.write("<div id = flagImage><img src = " + link[random_num].flag + " alt = Flag width = 50%></div>");
                </script>

            </div>


            <div class="guessEnter">
                <form onsubmit="checkGuess()">

                    <input type="text" id="guess" value="" placeholder="Make a guess...">

                    <div class="submitButton">
                        <input type="submit" onclick="checkGuess();">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>`
```


JS:

`/* Pulls random image to display on page */

random_num = (Math.round((Math.random() * 4) + 1));

link = new Array;

link[1] = { flag: "../assets/flagImages/ad.png", value: 'andorra' };
link[2] = { flag: "../assets/flagImages/ae.png", value: 'uae' + 'united arab emirates' }
link[3] = { flag: "../assets/flagImages/af.png", value: 'afghanistan' };
link[4] = { flag: "../assets/flagImages/ag.png", value: 'antigua and barbuda' };



/* Function that compares user input to link value */

var guess = document.getElementById("input").value;


function checkGuess() {

    event.preventDefault()

    if (link[random_num].value.toLowerCase() === guess.toLowerCase()) {
        alert('Correct!'); //correct guess 
    } else {
        alert('Wrong!'); //wrong guess 
    }

}
`
````

Comment: Please be specific regarding what "issues" your function has; don't make us guess.

Comment: There are loads of duplicates to this (goes hunting) but the problem appears to be that you are reading the value of the input when the page loads instead of after the user has typed something into it and clicked the button.

Comment: `random_num` is spelt differently here: `link[randum_num]`; not sure if that could be anything to do with it.

Comment: @BenStephens oops, I had it written the right way but changed it by trying something else, then rewrote it before posting this and had a typo. It did not work beforehand when spelled correctly.

Comment: @mykaf I don't know what the problem is so I don't know what to ask. The issue is it doesn't work, lol.

Comment: `document.getElementById("input").value` should probably be "guess", not "input"

Comment: What's the actual result vs expected result?

Comment: @mykaf the expected result is, when the form is submitted, for an alert popup to display if you are correct or incorrect (if the value of the image correlates to the guess), the actual result is... nothing happens.